# POST Request not working with Python, but working with Java

Tags: java, python, rest, python-requests, httpconnection

I am going to transform java code to python code.
but login POST request is not working via python code.

```
// Java code
        String inputData = “{\"lang\" : \"ko\", \"loginName\" : \"kkstar123\", \"password\" : \"123123123\"}”;
        String strUrl = “http://10.110.120.80/management/user/login.json”;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(strUrl).openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setDoInput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");                
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=\"UTF-8\"");
        OutputStream out = conn.getOutputStream(); // if remove OutputStream, it return 404 error
        out.write(inputData.getBytes());
        out.close();     
        System.out.println(conn.getResponseCode());
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader((InputStream)conn.getContent());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(in);
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            sb.append(line).append("\n");
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Above works fine, but.. below python code return 404 error

```
// python code
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

header = {
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset="UTF-8"',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Mobile Safari/537.36'
}

payload = {
    "lang": "ko",
    "loginName": "kkstar123",
    "password": "123123123"
}

loginURL = "http://10.110.120.80/management/user/login.json"

with requests.Session() as s:
    login_req = s.post(loginURL, data = payload, headers = header)
    print(login_req)
    print(html)
```

What is the problem? plz help me to resolve this issue. (if i use selenium, it works fine! but i want get request and response quickly! so i am trying to use requests api)

Comment: Can you also post the error message ?

Answer (score 0):

I should't use 'data' param for POST request. after change this to json, it works. i think i add the Content-Type into header with JSON, so i should use json param.

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked if the request sent in the browser involves any cookies?
If there are cookies present, you'll need to convert those cookies using SimpleCookie and add them to request's headers.
Also, create a Session object from requests as it will be better.